# How do I use voice recognition for my Android timer app?

Tags: android, timer, voice-recognition, voice

I have an Android application.

[image]

However, the whole point is that it is a mobile application to help users track, record, and monitor their shower usage and water consumption. In the app, there is a timer where you hit play, as seen in the picture. The user can set the phone down on a toilet lid, and leave the timer running, and then hit stop when they are done with the shower. The point is that they are conscious of the timer running, and want to minimize the length as much as possible.

The only problem is that sometimes people may not want to use their hand, so I thought they might want to stop the timer with their voice while the timer is running.

Does anyone have good suggestions where the microphone is turned on for the voice recognition during the duration of the whole shower while the timer is running. In other words, a continuous voice recognition for this scenario.

Really would appreciate some tips from the pros!

THANKS!!!

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you could try [App Actions using Google Assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app)

Comment: Is something not clear that I could clarify. Simply put, I need the microphone to be continuously capturing audio when the timer is running during the shower.  Any libraries you would recommend. The app actions isn’t working correctly